# How to get the paragraph having strong tag and the three paragraphs below it using BeautifulSoup and Python requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to get the paragraph having strong tag and the three paragraphs below it using BeautifulSoup and Python requests?
Screenshot of the paragraphs i want to get using BeautifulSoup.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


URL = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-200601'
headers={
    'user-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
    }

page =  requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


data = soup.find('p', text=re.compile('^Examples'))

print(data)
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Oh and post the (partial) HTML code too as part of your question and not as an image.

Comment: i just started using beautifulSoup, these paragraphs do not have any class or id, i tried getting the para with strong tag by writing soup.find('p', text='Examples') but it doesn't work.

Comment: could you please include the exact input and output in the question (as text)?

Comment: the html is really messy. A div with many paragraphs with no id or class, the paragraphs i want to extract is somewhat midway in the div and that too changes with every other post, please have a look at the screenshot attached. I am also including the link to the website, i want to get the Example and three paragraphs below it.  https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-200601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will get all paragraphs under the header `"Examples"`"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-200420'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

def get_paragraphs(first_paragraph):
    current_paragraph = first_paragraph
    while True:
        yield current_paragraph

        current_paragraph = current_paragraph.find_next('p')
        if not current_paragraph or (current_paragraph.strong and current_paragraph.strong.text.strip() != ''):
            break

for p in get_paragraphs(soup.select_one('p:contains("Examples")')):
    print(p)
```

Prints:

```
<p><strong>Examples</strong></p>
<p><br/>My friend keeps banging on about where he’s going to go when he buys his new car. It’s really frustrating.</p>
<p>That person on the bus was really annoying. She kept banging on about how the prices had gone up.</p>
<p>Will you please stop banging on about my project!? If you think you could do a better job, you can do my work for me.</p>
```

---

For `url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-200601'` it prints:

```
<p><strong>Examples<br/></strong>He’s always flexing on social media, - showing these glamorous pictures of his holidays! </p>
<p>People who flex are so annoying! It’s just showing off. </p>
<p>She can’t stop flexing about her new house, but it’s actually not that nice.<strong> </strong></p>
```